# Volley Server error<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF/, Volley Server Error, JSONArray not converting, When Retrofit,Postman Executing url

Tags: android, api, android-volley

1. com.android.volley.ServerError
2. I used Volley `JSONArray` request its directly receive error response

   ```
   RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());
       try {
           String url = getResources().getString(R.string.BASE_URL_SHARE) + "bank-nifty-top.txt";
           Log.d(TAG, "URL : " + url);
           JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                   Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

   try {
                       Log.d(TAG, "data recieved Shares: " + response.toString());
                       if (response != null) {
                           showMarketRates(response);
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "request" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       }
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       Log.d(TAG, "Volley" + e.toString());
                       Log.d(TAG, "Unable to contact server. please try again");
                   }
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                   checkInternet();
                   Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.toString());
                   NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                   if ((error instanceof ServerError) && response != null) {
                       try {
                           String res = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                           Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + res);
                           if (res != null) {
                               JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                               if (obj != null) {
                                   Log.d(TAG, "Err Desc: " + obj.getString("error_description"));
                                   return;
                               }
                               return;
                           }
                           Log.d(TAG, "Unable to contact server. please try again");
                       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                           Log.d(TAG, e1.toString());
                       } catch (JSONException e2) {
                           Log.d(TAG, e2.toString());
                       }
                   }
               }
           }) {
           };
           jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, 2, 2.0f));
           queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
       }
   ```

Comment: Can you add the code that you gave you this error and can you also explain a bit more ?

Comment: Problem is in server response. You are getting response in non JSONArray format.

Comment: your server response is not JSON

Comment: In postman it showing JSON Array , Using Retrofit its  fine , but Volley showing this bugs, I need  from Volley

Comment: Its solved by replacing the  ("https://" to "http://") or ("http://'' to "https://") in the Url

Answer (score 0):

Because you are receiving a HTML response or an error occurred not a JSON array, you need to check the server side.

Comment: I checked in postman its works fine , In volley it shows error  ,I added the code